# why's getChildId-method in BaseExpandableListAdapter looping three times

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I am working with `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and cannot really undertstand why the method `getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)` loops three times when I click the one and only child that exists in that groupposition?

I want something to happend when the childitem is clicked but the problem is that the program executes that three times, despite I only have one child.

Through System.out.println("")` one can see that the string is printed 3 times. why?

Maybe I missed something crucial? Should I use another method for intance?

Cincerely Björn

```
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
          System.out.println("childPosition: " + childPosition + " groupPosition: " + groupPosition);

          switch (childPosition) {
            case 0:
                // Do something
                break;
            case 1: 
                // Do something
                break;
          }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enter code here`You are not supposed to do anything in `getChildId` you should only return the id. You should do everything in `ExpandableListActivity.onChildClick` and such.

That is, getChildId should not change the state of your program. Because it can be called arbitrarily by the Android framework.

Just return something like `groupPosition*100 + childPosition`. Then in `ExpandableListActivity.onChildClick` and such you can figure out the id by the same formula.

Comment: MANY THANKS!!! :-) setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener()